# JPA - findById with @PostFilter: Filter target must be a collection or array type, but was Optional

Tags: security, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I just updated my application to Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE and found out my SpEL in @PostFilter is not working anymore:

```
@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated()")
@PostFilter("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or @companyService.isOwnerOfPerson(#id, principal)")
@Override
public Optional<Person> findById(@Param("id") String id);
```

The error is
    org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Filter target must be a collection or array type, but was Optional[Person ...]

I have seen that this is being discussed on https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15878 but I was trying to get a work around up and running: I extended DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler and overwrote the setReturnObject method as suggested in the ticket referenced above:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject, EvaluationContext ctx) {
        if (returnObject instanceof Optional) {
            Optional<?> optional = (Optional<?>)returnObject;

            Object value = null;
            if (optional.isPresent()) {
                value = optional.get();
            }

            ((MethodSecurityExpressionOperations) ctx.getRootObject().getValue())
            .setReturnObject(value);
        } else {
            super.setReturnObject(returnObject, ctx);
        }
    }

}
```

Next, I configured method security as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

}
```

I am not sure this is how it is supposed to be, but I know that it does not work yet ;)

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this bug appears because @PostFilter only works on collections (or arrays) as return values while findById only returns an optional of a single value. You can see it in your exception message:

> Filter target must be a collection or array type

Answer (score 0):

Slave trade is generally frowned upon "Company.isOwnerOfPerson" :). Problem in not in Spring. There are so many better ways of doing what ever you are trying to do, which is unclear in your code snipplet. That @companyService.isOwnerOfPerson( #id, principal) smelles like a mess:

If you have good Entity relation like: Company -(owner)-> Person ->User Entity relation, you can get the person of current user:

```
Optional<Person> findByUser(Principal user);
```

Spring Data will Autowire the Principal from SecurityContext and the method return person related to current user, really efficient and secure.

of in your Company repo you could get company of the current user :

```
Optional<Company> findByOwner_User(Principal user);
```

Or with that `@companyService.isOwnerOfPerson( #id, principal)` mess:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or @companyService.isOwnerOfPerson( #id, principal)")
@Override
public Optional<Person> findById(@Param("id") String id);
```

You have no need for POST processing and isAuthenticated is reduntant as both sides of OR require a authenticated user to exist (unless your security config is "something else").

Or if really want to filter just because you really want to "filter" a single item:
@PostFilter("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or @companyService.isOwnerOfPerson( returnObject.orElse(false).id, principal)")
@Override
public Optional findById(@Param("id") String id);

`returnObject` is the object returned by the method. And in this case it is `Optional<Person>` so you need to call `get()` or a null safe method of Optional like `orElse(false)` and then what even field or method you need from Person, like  field `id`. By they you could just as well use @PreFilter too for  your code.